# Recurrence relation: composition of a polynomial function

Tags: recurrence-relations

Let $f(x)=a+bx^2$. Define $f_n(x)$ to be the $n$-fold composition of $f$. That is
$$f_1(x)=f(x)$$
$$f_2(x)=f \circ f(x)$$
$$f_n(x)=f \circ f_{n-1}(x), n \ge 2$$

Is there a way to find a formula for $f_n$?

I tried to write down $f_2$, $f_3,\ldots$, but I don't see any pattern.

Comment: [I don't think there's a simple expression for the $n$-th iterate...](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a simple change of variables, you will be iterating $z^2+c$ for some $c$.  There *is* a simple formula for the $n$th iterate when $c=0$ or $c=-2$.  But not otherwise.

**added**

Double-angle formula: $\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2-1$, so if we write
$z=2\cos\theta$, then we get $f_1 = z^2-2 = 2\cos 2\theta$ ;
$f_2 = (z^2-2)^2-2 = 2\cos 4\theta$ ; and so on ... $f_n = 2\cos(2^n\theta)$.  If you like, put $\theta = \arccos(z/2)$ into these.

Comment: I can't figure the simple expression for the case $c=-2$. I tried

$$f_1=z^2-2$$
$$f_2=z^4-4z+2$$
$$f_3=f_2^2-2$$

But at $f_3$, I'm blocked, and I can't identify a formula. Thanks.

Comment: For the $c=-2$ case, remember the double-angle formula for cosines.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had it clear, but I'm not sure of how to apply the double-angle formula here. Can you show me for $f_2$. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much GEdgar. It's was the first for me to use the angle formula is such context. I was very hesitant at each step. But your precision make me confident now. Thanks.

Comment: Is the formula we derived valid $\forall z \in \mathbb R$?
Sorry if this is elementary, I'm confused since $0 \leq cos(\theta) \leq 1, \forall \theta \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: There is no reason $z$ must be real, either; it could be complex.  So allow $\theta$ to be complex, too.  However, if you want real $z$ with $z>2$ there is a similar formula with hyperbolic cosine.

Comment: @Nicolas: or you can recast the whole bit in terms of Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind...

Comment: @J. M.: In other words, you are asking for a "formula" for the Chebyshev polynomials...???

Comment: I sure as peas ain't. ;) I'm noting the cosine/hyperbolic cosine bit can be unified if you switch to Chebyshev's formulation, that's all...

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a "nice" formula for $f_n$ or even a pattern.  Here's my reasoning:

If the graph of $y = a + bx^2$ intersects the line $y=x$, then there can be chaotic behavior in the values $f_n(x)$ for general $x$.  See the neat animation on the Wiki article for "cobweb plot":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot

Hope this helps!

Comment: Of course, there are some special cases of note.  If $a = 0$, then it's fairly easy to find the general formula: $f_n(x) = b^{2^n - 1}x^{2^n}$.